# Dynamically Splitting Images

Tags: php, image-processing

Does anyone know of a PHP routine where I can take an original image and split it in half to create two new images A and B?

See below:

[alt text http://www.bellschofield.eu/zqocc89c.jpg](http://www.bellschofield.eu/zqocc89c.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: see if this helps http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4166-PHP-Split-large-images-in-smaller-tiles.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<?php
$width = 100;
$height = 100;

$source = @imagecreatefromjpeg( "source.jpg" );
$source_width = imagesx( $source );
$source_height = imagesy( $source );

for( $col = 0; $col < $source_width / $width; $col++)
{
    for( $row = 0; $row < $source_height / $height; $row++)
    {
        $fn = sprintf( "img%02d_%02d.jpg", $col, $row );

        echo( "$fn\n" );

        $im = @imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
        imagecopyresized( $im, $source, 0, 0,
            $col * $width, $row * $height, $width, $height,
            $width, $height );
        imagejpeg( $im, $fn );
        imagedestroy( $im );
        }
    } 
    ?>
```

The code above takes input from a source file : "source.jpg". It splits the file into 100x100 pixels and names the files img00_01.jpg and so on.... You can change the height, width of the resulting image by changing the $height and $width parameters..

Comment: how and where to see those splitted images?

Comment: imagejpeg( $im, $fn ); $fn is the destination of splited images.
it works thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Read about PHP [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php). You will need methods like: imagecreatefromjpeg() (or other, depends on your source file), imagecreatetruecolor(), imagecopy(), imagejpeg().

Comment: `imagecopy` is the one! ► https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php