# How to retrieve value in php in in diffrent div?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Hi  iam trying to retrieve value from database in php where i want to  retrievevalue . i  want to retrieve half image in one div and another half value in another value how can i do this.

i tried to achive like this but i am unable to achieve this

here is my code

```
<?php
    $query="select adds from subcategory adds where subcategoryname= 'Preschool'";
    $data=mysqli_query($db,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
    {
        $my=  $row['adds'];     
    }

?>
```

here is my 2 div

```
<div id="1" >
</div>

<div id="2">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you store your images in the database?
It is not so clear to me what are you trying to do.

Comment: do you want retrieve  image in database and show in `DIV` ?

Comment: Please rephrase so it's understandable... and specify what you mean by "image" (path of the image? the image data itself?)... and are you trying to split the image (singular) in half in 2 divs, or you are trying to display multiple images and separate them in 2 divs? That's a bit unclear

Comment: @Radasca   i am trying to retrieve value from database in d html div section

Comment: You code have a `}` left.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [a piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911256/dynamically-splitting-images) that split images and I edited it to fill your needs.

```
<?php

    $source = @imagecreatefromjpeg( $my );
    $source_width = imagesx( $source );
    $source_height = imagesy( $source );

    $width = $source_width/2;
    $height = $source_width/2;

    for( $col = 0; $col <= $width; $col+=$width)
    {
        for( $row = 0; $row <= $height ; $row+=$height)
        {
            $fn = sprintf( "img%02d_%02d.jpg", $col, $row );

            echo( "$fn\n" );

            $im = @imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
            imagecopyresized( $im, $source, 0, 0,
                $col * $width, $row * $height, $width, $height,
                $width, $height );
            imagejpeg( $im, $fn );
        imagedestroy( $im );
?>

    <div id="<?php echo $col==0 ? 1:2 ;?>">
        <img src="<?php echo sprintf( "img%02d_%02d.jpg", $col, $row);?>"/> 
    </div>
<?php
        }
    } 
?>
```

I hope it will work