# PHP - Split image on load

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Is there anyway to split an image into two or three or four images onload? I want to wrap a content with 4 sides where each side has the 25% of the image width. Is it possible?

Comment: dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911256/dynamically-splitting-images

Comment: You probably want to use a technique called image sprite : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Implementing_image_sprites_in_CSS